# How can I access my angular resource from the developer console?

Tags: angularjs, developer-tools

I have this resource:

```
angular.module('showboardApp')
  .factory('Session', function () {
    return $resource('/api/session.json');
  });
```

I would like to access it from the chrome developer console.  Is there some way to inject it and run immediately with similar syntax to this?

```
angular.module('showboardApp')
  .run(function(Session){
    var promise = Post.query();
    console.log(promise);
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you basically need is your app's **[injector](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector)**. Then you can use it to inject your service to a function and execute some code with it. E.g.:

```
var inj = angular.injector(['showboardApp']);
inj.invoke(function (Session) {...});
```

Comment: I get this error when trying to load my resource 'Person': Module 'Person' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini: This is probably not what you want. If you want to gain access to the **same instance** of a service that your app is using, take a look at **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595460/how-to-access-update-rootscope-from-outside-angular/24596251#answer-24596251)**.